# Run 2 copies of Jboss 6.1.0 in same machine, same time and same application

Tags: jboss6.x

Hi Can some one provide me step by step guide to run 2 JBoss 6.1.0 Final in the same machine with different ports? My requirement is that i want to run same web application at same time in 2 different JBoss6.1.0 Final instances. one should be running on port 8080 and other one should be running on 8180.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the information [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOneMachine)

Assuming you have two profiles (node1 and node2) you can run these two commands to run two instances

```
./run.sh -c node1
./run.sh -c node2 -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1
```

Comment: Thanks jBug, what if want to run default and node1 only, i tried to run default './run.sh -c default' and node1 './run.sh -c node1 -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1' bu it gave me 'ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use' error

Comment: That's interesting. Which port is it complaining about?

Comment: this is the error iam getting >>> 
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
Press any key to continue . . .